# Red Black Tree Insert Issues C++

Tags: c++, pointers, exc-bad-access, null, red-black-tree

I'm currently working on an assignment where I am to implement a simple version of a Red Black Tree. I am currently working in Xcode and it's currently giving me an error `GDB: Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS`... which I am assuming is a memory leak... but I can't seem to spot any reason as to why this is happening. The debugger has shown me the issue is in my `RedBlackTree::treeInsert(char *data)` function.... specifically with the if statement in the body of the while loop `if (strcmp(data, x->data) < 0)`.

the debugger shows that `this = 0x7fff5fc01052` and `data = 0x100001a61` which is storing a char (letter A). However it shows that `x = 0x4810c48348ec8948` but all of its properties (parent, left, right, data) are all empty.

So the next thing i have tried was making sure that i initialize these variables as `Nil` in my `node()` constructor. But this gave me the error: `'Nil' was not declared in this scope`... so I currently have them commented out. Not sure what is going on here..? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class node
{
public:
char         *data;         // Data containing one character
node         *parent;       // pointer to this node's parent
node         *left;          // pointer to this node's left child
node         *right;          // pointer to this node's right child
bool         isRed;         // bool value to specify color of node
node();
};

node::node(){
this->data = new char[1];
isRed = true;
//this->parent = Nil;
//this->left = Nil;
//this->right = Nil;
}
```

**red black tree class and methods**

```
class RedBlackTree {
public: 
/*constructor*/
RedBlackTree();

node* getRoot(){
    return this->Root;
}

/*RB-INSERT*/
void rbInsert(char *data);
node treeInsert(char *data);
void rbInsertFixup(node *z);

/*ROTATE*/
void leftRotate(node *z);
void rightRotate(node *z);

/*INORDER TRAVERSAL*/
void inOrderPrint(node *root);



private:
node    *Root;    /*root*/
node    *Nil;    /*leaf*/

};



RedBlackTree::RedBlackTree() 
{
this->Nil = new node();
this->Root = Nil;
}

void RedBlackTree::rbInsert(char *data){
node z = treeInsert(data);
rbInsertFixup(&z);  

} // end rbInsert()

node RedBlackTree::treeInsert(char *data){

node *x;
node *y;
node *z;

y = Nil;
x = Root;
while (x!= Nil) {
    y = x;
    if (strcmp(data, x->data) < 0) {
        x = x->left;
    } else {
        x = x->right;
    }
}
z = new node(); // create a new node
z->data = data;
z->parent = y;
z->isRed = true; // set  new node as red 
z->left = Nil;
z->right = Nil;

if (y == Nil) {
    Root = z;
} else {
    if (strcmp(data, y->data)<= 0) {
        y->left = z;
    } else {
        y->right = z;
    }

}
return *z;
}
```

**here is my main function**

```
int main(){


RedBlackTree *RBT;
node* root = RBT->getRoot();
RBT->rbInsert((char *)"A");
RBT->inOrderPrint(root);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why use a special `Nil` node instead of `nullptr` (or `0`)? And if data is only a single character, why use an array of one and allocate it dynamically when you can use a single `char` and no pointers instead?

Comment: You're violating the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) there cupcake. You're also leaking memory.

Answer (score 1):

You have buffer overflows all over the place! A string containing one character is actually **two** characters, as it has a special terminating character as well. You allocate memory for a single character for the data, but your use of strings will make these buffers overflow.

Answer (score 0):

In main you just have a pointer in RBT to the tree without initing it, and call away to the undefined behavior land.

(and the code have a ton of other suspect points)

Comment: yeah, that too :-o  After the first half-dozen I decided it not worth pointing out individually.